# JQuery UI Dialog Image can't show

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, d3.js, dialog

I have a visualization task using JQuery UI Dialog and d3. There are many nodes in the graph, I want to open a popup box when click a node. The contents and image of that node will be shown on the popup. The code is like below.

Currently, the popup box doesn't show image, only show contents and title. However, if I move the dialog open function out of function click(). The image can show correctly. I don't know why. Any suggestion is appreciated! Thanks!

```
<body>
   <div id="contents" style="display:none">
      Popup Contents
      <img id="image" src="" />
   </div>
   <script>
       var graph={};
       var force = d3.layout.force()
      .charge(-500)
      .linkDistance(30)
      .size([width-400, height]);

      var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("height", height).attr("width", width);

      d3.csv("nodes.csv", function(d){
         return {
          id: +d.id,
          name: d.name,
         }; 
      }, function(error, nodes){
            graph.nodes = nodes;
            var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
                          .data(graph.nodes)
                          .enter().append("circle")
                          .on("click", click);
        });
     });
     function click(d,e) {
         uri = 'images/a.png'
         $('#contents').attr("title",name)
         .dialog({
              width:'auto',
              height:'auto',
              modal: true,
              open: function(event, ui){
                 $('#image').attr('src',uri);
              }
     });
```

Comment: The code as you've posted it should work fine. Is this the code you're experiencing the problem with?

Comment: I have figured this out. That's due to I reset the contents of #contents div in click function, which further remove the #image div when I click a node.